# WHY I'M GETTING SEGMENT VIOLATION

Tags: c

I'm making a basic shell. When I run my shell and use Enter and nothing more in the line the program crash and gives me a segment violation:

Uvash>

Violación de segmento (`core' generado)

(Uvash> is the line were I type the commands while running the shell)

I think that the problems is in my function: principal() for using getline(), but I used it other times and \n works well

```
Here's my code:

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define INTERACTIVO 0
#define NO_INTERACTIVO 1
#define MAX_ARGS 128


char error_message[30]= "An error has occurred\n";
int modo;

void principal(FILE *f);
void separado(char *comando);
int builtInCommands(char *miArgv[], int miArgc);
void creaProceso(char *miArgv[], int argc);

int main(int argc, char *args[]){

    //En caso de haber más de dos argumentos no es ni modo interactivo ni modo batch
    if (argc > 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", error_message);
    exit(1);
    }
    
    FILE *fd;
    //Corresponde a modo interactivo
    if (argc < 2){
    fd = stdin;
    modo = INTERACTIVO;
    }

    //En caso de no ser modo interactivo tomar fichero para los comandos
    else{
    fd = fopen(args[1],"r");
    modo = NO_INTERACTIVO;
    if (fd == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", error_message);
        exit(1);
    }
 
    }
    
    principal(fd);

    exit(0); 
    
}

void principal (FILE *f){

    char *comando = NULL;
    size_t valor = 0;
    ssize_t tam = 0;
   
    if (modo == INTERACTIVO){
    printf("Uvash>");
    }

    while((tam = getline(&comando, &valor, f)) != -1){  
        
    printf("Entra getline");    
    //Quitar fin de linea
    if (tam > 0){
       comando[tam-1] = '\0';
    }
    
    
    //Getline se detiene (Introducir Ctrl+D corresponde a EOF --> getline se detiene)
        else{
        printf("\n");
        exit(0);
        }
    
    separado(comando);
    if (modo == INTERACTIVO){
        printf("Uvash>");
    }

    }

    free(comando);
    comando = NULL;
    valor = 0;
}

void separado(char *comando){
    
    char *comandoT = comando;
    char *delimitador = " ";
    int i = 0;
    char **miArgv; //Será de tamaño TAM_MAX
    
    miArgv = (char **) malloc(MAX_ARGS*sizeof(char*));
    
    
    char *palabra = strtok(comandoT, delimitador);
    miArgv[i] = palabra;
    if (palabra != NULL){
    while(palabra != NULL){
        palabra = strtok(NULL, delimitador);
        i ++;
        miArgv[i] = palabra;
    }
    }
    i++;
    miArgv[i] = NULL;

    //Ahora la llamada a la función que hace el fork
    int seguir = builtInCommands(miArgv,i);
    
    
    //Solo en caso de que no sea uno de los builtInCommands hará falta llamar a creaProceso()
    if (seguir == TRUE){
    creaProceso(miArgv,i);
    }
    
    
   free(miArgv);
}

int builtInCommands(char *miArgv[], int miArgc){
    char cadena[5] = "exit";
    char cadena2[3] = "cd";

    int seguir = TRUE;

    if (strstr(miArgv[0],cadena) != NULL){
    if (miArgc > 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", error_message);
        exit(0);
    }
    seguir = FALSE;
    exit(0);
    }

    if (strstr(miArgv[0],cadena2) != NULL){
    if (miArgc > 3 || miArgc<3){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", error_message);
        exit(0);
    }

    else{
        chdir(miArgv[1]);
        seguir = FALSE;
    }
        
    }

    return seguir;
}

void creaProceso(char *miArgv[], int miArgc){

    
    printf("Entra proceso");    
    pid_t pidHijo;

    pidHijo = fork();
    if (pidHijo == 0){
    if (execvp(miArgv[0], miArgv) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", error_message);
        exit(1);
    }   
    }
    wait(NULL); 
    
}
```

Comment: Perhaps not related to your question but in 'void principal' you are 'free()'ing a pointer variable that is not dynamically allocated, and then you are assigning it a null pointer after 'free()'.

Comment: "*I think*". Now would be a good time to learn how to debug your own code to have a good chance of going from thinking to knowing. Run your program in a debugger. At a minimum it will instantly give you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. Can also use it to examine the program as it runs. More debugging tips: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The line `char *palabra = strtok(comandoT, delimitador);` sets `palabra` to a null pointer, then `miArgv[i] = palabra;` sets `miArgv[0]` to a null pointer, and later `if (strstr(miArgv[0],cadena) != NULL)` attempts to use that pointer, so the program crashes.

Comment: @kaylum - the sad part about that article is that it doesnt tell you how to use a debugger, or that such a thing even exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric mentioned in the comments, you passed NULL as the first parameter to strstr which caused the Segmentation Fault. Here is a debugging session with lldb that shows this:

```
~/tmp $ clang -g -O0 prog.c
~/tmp $ lldb ./a.out
(lldb) target create "./a.out"
Current executable set to '/Users/billmorgan/tmp/a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 27787 launched: '/Users/billmorgan/tmp/a.out' (x86_64)
Uvash>
Process 27787 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff2090f1e6 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strstr + 42
libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strstr:
->  0x7fff2090f1e6 <+42>: movb   (%r15), %al
    0x7fff2090f1e9 <+45>: testb  %al, %al
    0x7fff2090f1eb <+47>: je     0x7fff2090f211            ; <+85>
    0x7fff2090f1ed <+49>: movq   %r15, %rbx
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
(lldb) up
frame #1: 0x0000000100003d3c a.out`builtInCommands(miArgv=0x0000000101808200, miArgc=1) at prog.c:138:9
   135 
   136      int seguir = TRUE;
   137 
-> 138      if (strstr(miArgv[0],cadena) != NULL){
   139      if (miArgc > 2){
   140          fprintf(stderr, "%s", error_message);
   141          exit(0);
(lldb) p miArgv[0]
(char *) $0 = 0x0000000000000000
(lldb) q
Quitting LLDB will kill one or more processes. Do you really want to proceed: [Y/n] 
~/tmp $
```